# JavaScript. Check if value is not in object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 list. One bigger and one smaller. I have added infinite scroll to keep adding items from bigger list to smaller one.

```
// Bigger list (data from DB)
var data; 
// Smaller list 
$scope.projects = [];

$scope.$watch('projectSearch', function (val) {
    if (typeof val !== 'undefined' && val !== "") {
        //console.log("SEARCH: " + val);
        for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
            if (data[a].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1) {
                console.log("FOUND: " + data[a].name);
                if($scope.projects.indexOf(data[a].name) === -1) {
                    console.log("PUSHED " + data[a].name);
                    $scope.projects.push( data[a]);

                } else {
                    console.log("ALREADY IN " + data[a].name);
                }
            }
        }
    }  
});
```

Search form:

```
<input id="search" ng-model="projectSearch" placeholder="Search ..."/>
```

The problem is it keeps pushing items to new list. It does not check this if statement correctly

```
if($scope.projects.indexOf(data[a].name) === -1) {
    console.log("PUSHED " + data[a].name);
    $scope.projects.push( data[a]);
}
```

Comment: You are not pushing the `name`. `$scope.projects.push(data[a].name);`

Comment: I push object, this one works fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should check for `data[a]`, not its property `name`

```
if($scope.projects.indexOf(data[a]) === -1) {
    console.log("PUSHED " + data[a].name);
    $scope.projects.push( data[a]);
}
```

also, you could remove `data[a]` after copy to make next search faster

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.projects` should be type of `string` assuming `data[a].name` is string then your indexOf function properly

Comment: I push only objects which contain characters from input field. I do not check if it's string.